# how to add a unique id to a onclick event

Tags: javascript, uniqueidentifier

I am having some code between pre tags and I want to catch al that code with an onclick event 
My html structure is like below:

```
<div class="Message">
  <div class="surroundpre">
     <span class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, \\\'id1\\\')">[Select and Copy]</span>
     <pre class="CodeBlock id="id22015640">
        <!-- code goes her -->
     </pre>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The pre elements and the div with class surroundpre is created by javascript.
The unique id for the pre:

```
$('pre').each(function(){

    if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined){
        $(this).attr('id','id'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999) + 1))
    }
 });
```

The div with surroundpre is created like below:

```
$('.Message .CodeBlock', this).wrap('<div class=surroundpre></div>');
```

The span is created with php variable:

```
 $SelectButton = '<span class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, \\\'id1\\\')">[Select and Copy]</span><br />';
```

in combination with:

```
$('.surroundpre').prepend('$SelectButton');
```

My question: the **id1** in the php variable should be replaced with the same unique id as in the pre tag.
How can I achieve this?
Or is there an other method to achieve this?

Comment: Using `random` to generate a unique id may be less preferable than a simple counter. IE `var nextUniqueIDCounter = 0;` then `$(this).prop('id', 'id' + nextUniqueIDCounter++);`

Comment: You say `php variable`... Is `$SelectButton = '<span class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, \\\'$aa\\\')">[Select and Copy]</span><br />';` generated in PHP? How are you calling it? Is it being called before the page loads?

Comment: Yes, all this code is in a public function; and the javascript is in a .livequery(function () A big string of a php variable: $Result = "jQuery(document).ready(function($) { .....and so on....

Comment: PHP generates before Javascript is loaded, so matching the ID in PHP after javascript is generated is impossible. You should either generate the ID in PHP and load it into Javascript or likely rethink your whole structure. Generally combinging HTML, Javascript, and PHP results in hard to work with code. For example, the ugly slash grave in the code `$SelectButton = '<span class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, \\\'id1\\\')">[Select and Copy]</span><br />';`

Comment: I agree the combination of php with javascript is difficult. But how can I achieve the same result with jquery only to create a span just in front of the pre tag with onclick event and with the same unique id as is in the pre tag?

Comment: What is your goal exactly? Not your programmatic goal, but your software design requirements. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to achieve with this, but perhaps here is an example of how you can relate elements without even needing an ID. https://jsfiddle.net/59vbd1ff/1/

Comment: What I am trying to achieve: just before the pre tag should be a span with onclik event and with the same unique id as in the pre tag; so I can catch all the code in the pre tag. Everything is done already except the span with onclick event and the id. Don't know how to parse that same unique id as in the pre tag in the span

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98037/discussion-between-tom-and-nuet).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you, make a few changes, first in PHP:

```
$SelectButton = '<span class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, this.getAttribute(\"data-block-id\"))">[Select and Copy]</span><br />';
```

Then in JS:

```
$('pre').each(function(){
    var id;
    if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined){
        id = 'id'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999) + 1);
        $(this).attr('id',id);
        $(this).prev('span').attr('data-block-id',id);
    }
 });
```

Now the id generated in js is attached to the span at the same time of creation, when it is available to you, and the pregenerated (in PHP) onclick event can access it when it needs it (as long as that is after the ID setting code has run).